# Problem of rooms

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

A rectangle is divided into some smaller rectangles.Each two adjacent rectangles share a door which connects them.Prove that we can start from one of the small rectangles and pass them all without crossing a rectangle more than once.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @user3482749 I tried to solve this problem by Induction.

Comment: And? What progress did you make?

Comment: Not an answer, but there are planar graphs which have no Hamiltonian paths, so the result, if true, must rely on the constraint on the graph implied by the conditions that each room is a rectangle, as is the whole building, and that any two abutting rooms must share a door.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip in the right direction. The main difficulty of an inductive argument would be the following hypothetical case:[image]

Here, it is not obvious how to adapt the pre-existing path to to include this new rectangle. So, why not make the inductive hypothesis be that there exists a path which never exits a rectangle, $r$, from the same "side" that $r$ was entered from, avoiding this problem altogether. With that inductive hypothesis, here’s the case work:

[image]

Hopefully everything is clear now?

Comment: Do you have another idea without using induction?

Comment: induction is by far most natural to me, are you still having difficulty?

Comment: Have you tried anything since?

Comment: please try to provide further guidance.

Comment: I've drawn the cases, did you understand what my inductive proposition is?

Comment: Exactly what are the steps you consider? If they all amount to bisecting one of the existing rectangles, then not all tilings of a rectangle with rectangles can be made that way. (Consider filling a 9x9 square with four 2x1 rectangles along the edges and a single 1x1 square in the middle).

Answer (score 0):

Convert the rectangular structure to a graph, where each door becomes a vertex and each room becomes an edge. Since each door connects exactly two rooms, each vertex is therefore of degree two. Since no vertex is of odd degree, a Eulerian cycle is possible, i.e. each room/edge/bridge can be visited without repetition.

Comment: Since rooms will generally have more than two doors, this requires thinking about "edges" that connect more than two "vertices". That is definitely not a standard concept of graphs, so the standard theorems (like the one you're appealing to) will not work.

Comment: And "a Eulerian _cycle_ is possible" is too strong a conclusion anyway. There are easy room layouts that will only allow for an Eulerian _trail_ (which may end in a different room from the one it started at).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of a simple room structure which produced a simple graph.